# How to handle azure event hub receiver properly in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm doing a small project on Microsoft Azure Event Hubs. I need to display the Activity Logs of my Azure subscription to the MVC application.

I was able to stream the event log to a service bus and I have an issue while receiving the data from EventHubReceiver. It seems the receiver just freezes if there is no data. I understand this is because of the pub sub architecture that eventhubs uses, but I would like to control the flow since I'm using a MVC application.

For now I have used CancellationToken and explicitly waiting for 6 seconds to let the EventReceiver receive all the messages. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var list = new List<Record>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
                {
                    var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://xcvxcv.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xcvxcvxvxvxcvxcccccccccccccccccccccccccc;TransportType=Amqp");
                    var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient("insights-operational-logs");

                    var group = client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup();
                    var receiver = group.CreateReceiver(state.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));


                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            receiver.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        var messages = receiver.Receive(10);
                        foreach (var message in messages)
                        {
                            var logMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEventMessage>(Encoding.Default.GetString(message.GetBytes()));
                            list.AddRange(logMessage.records);
                        }
                    }
                }, i);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            cts.Cancel();
            return View(list.OrderBy(o => o.time));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider implementing the EventProcessorHost interface and controlling the flow in ProcessEventsAsync.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/

Comment: The EventProcessorHost seems to be using a StorageAccount. Is it possible to do this without a storage account ?

Comment: The Storage Account is primarily used to store checkpoint information, so in ProcessEventsAsync, you do your work, then call checkpoint. Then if your application fails, you can pick up since the last time you checkpointed. Another reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/01/16/event-processor-host-best-practices-part-1/

Comment: this works perfectly fine in c# console app but how to use it inside mvc ?